# using PowerShell with Code::Blocks

Tags: powershell, codeblocks, gfortran

My machine is Win 7.

How can I change in Code::Blocks the shell from cmd to PowerShell?
Code:Blocks use the cmd as a shell, but I want that he will use the PowerShell instead.
How can I do that? my compiler is gfortran.

John

Comment: Code::Blocks _does not_ use CMD, it uses `cb_console_runner`, a thin wrapper around `CreateProcess`, which displays the numeric exit code, reports the time it took to execute the command, and optionally prompts for a keypress (if the checkbox in target options is set). You _can_ of course delete this wrapper program and `junction` the `powershell.exe` program to `cb_console_runer`'s original location, but you will gain nothing from that, apart from breaking built-into-IDE functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This not an real answer, but a suggestion. Do you try to change environement variable `ComSpec` ?

For example to :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```